# How to change UnicodeCategory in java?

Tags: java, unicode

I'm trying to migrate this C# code to Java.

Is there any possibility to migrate the unicodeCategory to a regex in Java, or is there a possibility to do the Unicode category by Java directly?

```
foreach (var currentChar in preNormalizedString)
{
    var unicodeCategory = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(currentChar);

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true
    switch (unicodeCategory)
    {
        //case UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark:
        //case UnicodeCategory.SpacingCombiningMark:
        //case UnicodeCategory.EnclosingMark:
        case UnicodeCategory.DashPunctuation:
        case UnicodeCategory.ConnectorPunctuation:
        case UnicodeCategory.OpenPunctuation:
        case UnicodeCategory.ClosePunctuation:
        case UnicodeCategory.OtherPunctuation:
        case UnicodeCategory.LineSeparator:
        case UnicodeCategory.MathSymbol:
        case UnicodeCategory.ModifierSymbol:
        case UnicodeCategory.OtherSymbol:
        case UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator:
        case UnicodeCategory.ParagraphSeparator:
            if (!isPreviousSpaceChar)
                builder.Append(" ");
            isPreviousSpaceChar = true;
            break;

        case UnicodeCategory.Control:
        case UnicodeCategory.CurrencySymbol:
        case UnicodeCategory.EnclosingMark:
        case UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark:
        case UnicodeCategory.SpacingCombiningMark:
        case UnicodeCategory.InitialQuotePunctuation:
        case UnicodeCategory.FinalQuotePunctuation:
        case UnicodeCategory.Format:
        case UnicodeCategory.ModifierLetter:
        case UnicodeCategory.OtherNotAssigned:
        case UnicodeCategory.PrivateUse:
        case UnicodeCategory.Surrogate:
            // Caratères ignorés.
            break;

        case UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter:
        case UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter:
        case UnicodeCategory.LetterNumber:
        case UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber:
        case UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter:
        case UnicodeCategory.OtherNumber:
        case UnicodeCategory.TitlecaseLetter:
        default:
            builder.Append(currentChar);
            isPreviousSpaceChar = false;
            break;
    }
}

var normalizedString = builder.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
normalizedString = normalizedString.ToUpper();
normalizedString = normalizedString.Trim();
return normalizedString;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [`getType(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType(char)) that will return an `int` that you can then compare with a list of constants that are enumerated in the Java Docs.

Note that both C# code and the `getType(char)` are "wrong" because they don't support non-BMP characters (characters that use two `char`). But splitting a string in its "Rune" was a little more complex in C# until .NET Core 3.0.

```
public static String convert(String preNormalizedString) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean isPreviousSpaceChar = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < preNormalizedString.length(); i++) {
        char currentChar = preNormalizedString.charAt(i);

        int unicodeCategory = Character.getType(currentChar);

        switch (unicodeCategory) {
            case Character.DASH_PUNCTUATION:
            case Character.CONNECTOR_PUNCTUATION:
                //... You'll have to complete the list
                if (!isPreviousSpaceChar)
                    builder.append(" ");

                isPreviousSpaceChar = true;
                break;
            case Character.CONTROL:
            case Character.CURRENCY_SYMBOL:
                //... You'll have to complete the list
                // Caratères ignorés.
                break;

            case Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER:
            case Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER:
                //... You'll have to complete the list
            default:
                builder.append(currentChar);
                break;
        }
    }

    String normalizedString = builder.toString();
    normalizedString = normalizedString.toUpperCase();
    normalizedString = normalizedString.trim();
    return normalizedString;
}
```

Comment: im getting an error in "var"  . how to change it in java by a String  ?

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa Removed the var. Ideone working: https://ideone.com/uc5tFG

Comment: Thanks @xanatos . Is there a method to this 
`  var preNormalizedString = stringToNormalize.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);`

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html

Comment: I've done this   String preNormalizedString = stringToNormalize.normalize(Normalizer.Form.class.D); but getting an error for the equivalent of NormalizationForm.FormD in C#

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa There is an example in the linked document: `normalized_string = Normalizer.normalize(target_chars, Normalizer.Form.NFD);` you should follow it instead of inventing everything

Comment: could i migrate this code to java ?  BirthDate = Row.Birthdate_IsNull ? null : (DateTime?)Row.Birthdate,

Comment: could you see my previous question ?

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa Don't know. I normally don't do java. `BirthDate = Row.Birthdate_IsNull ? null : Row.Birthdate` probably.